# delete core data from a row when swipe to delete is activated

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, swift3

Im working on a project in swift 3.0, and i'm populating data on a table view, which I save on a core data entity from another view controller (from two text fields). I wants to delete data when swipe to delete is activated both from my array and core data. my code on UITableView class as bellow.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import CoreData

class MyExpencesViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {


@IBOutlet weak var expensesTableView: UITableView!

var myExpensesArray = [String] ()
var myAmountArray = [String] ()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

   loadData()
   self.expensesTableView.reloadData()


}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return (myExpensesArray.count)
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell: MyExpensesTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! MyExpensesTableViewCell

    cell.myExpenseName.text = myExpensesArray [indexPath.row]
    cell.myExpenseAmount.text = myAmountArray [indexPath.row]

 return cell 
}

func loadData (){
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

    let request = NSFetchRequest <NSFetchRequestResult> (entityName: "UserExpenses")
    request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false

    do {

        let results = try context.fetch(request)


        // check data existance
        if results.count>0 {
            print(results.count)

            for resultGot in results as! [NSManagedObject]{

                if let expName = resultGot.value(forKey:"expenseName") as? String{

                    myExpensesArray += [expName]
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        [unowned self] in self.expensesTableView.reloadData()
                        self.expensesTableView.reloadData()
                    }



                    print("myExp array is : \(myExpensesArray)")
                }
                if let amountVal = resultGot.value(forKey:"amount") as? String{

                    myAmountArray += [amountVal]
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        [unowned self] in self.expensesTableView.reloadData()
                        self.expensesTableView.reloadData()
                    }



                    print("myAmount array is : \(myAmountArray)")
                }

            }





        }

    }catch{


        print("No Data to load in the array")
    }



  }


}
```

Comment: What's the question?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add 2 more methods for delete row on swipe

```
//For swipe access allow
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    return true
}

//For remove row from tableview & object from array.
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.delete) {
        // delete data and row
        <YourArray>.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
    }
}
```

let me know if you need more detail.

Comment: This doesn't remove my data from the core data. I'm looking for a code to delete from my core data as well. Because of that even though i delete from the tableview when i re-run the app it get loaded again and populate in my UItableview (look at my viewWillAppear method, there is a function to load data from core data)

Comment: so you have to mention that in your question that I want to delete data from core data entity.

Comment: would much appreciate if you could help on this though

Comment: i have an entity called UserExpenses and it got two attributes called expenseName and amount. There are two textFields to enter these details and once they've been entered and press save, they will be saved to core data. Then i'll be retrieving those two values in the viewController that i have uploaded the code above.